# Does the following property hold in groups?

Tags: group-theory

I know that for $G=(S,\circ)$ to be a group one property it need to have is that

$$\forall a,b\in S,\exists c\in S:a\circ b=c$$

but is it true that $\forall c\in S,\exists a,b\in S:a\circ b=c$ ?

I feel like this, or holds for any group or for a special type of group. Thanks.

Comment: The first statement is practically unrelated to this being a group (it is just the statement that you have a binary operation). The second one does hold in all groups (Hint: You can pick $a = c$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This holds trivially for any group.

Let $c \in S$. Then $c = c * e$ where $e$ is the identity in the group.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true, since $(\forall c\in S):c\circ e_S=c$, where $e_S$ is the identity element of $S$.